# Why is this nested variadic template an invalid argument?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

If I define a `struct` template `Bar` which accepts a template argument:

```
template <template <int,bool,char> class>
struct Bar {};
```

I can instantiate it using a `struct` template such as `Zod`:

```
template <int,bool,char> struct Zod {};
Bar<Zod> a;
```

I can also instantiate it using a nested `struct` template such as `JKL`:

```
struct GHI {
  template <int,bool,char>
  struct JKL {};
};
Bar <GHI::JKL> b;
```

Why can't I instantiate `Bar` using a nested variadic `struct` template such as `DEF`?:

```
template <typename ...Ts>
struct ABC {
  template <Ts ...>
  struct DEF {};
};

Bar<ABC<int,bool,char>::DEF> c;
```

G++ 4.9.2 complains of a type/value mismatch; while Clang 3.4.2's error reports that the template template argument has different template parameters than its corresponding template template parameter.

Comment: Doesn't compile on gcc 5.1.0 or clang 3.6.0 either, for what it's worth.

Comment: I am not able to instantiate the inner template either, `ABC<int,bool,char>::DEF foo;` doesn't work, `error: missing template arguments before foo`

Comment: @vsoftco [An explicit instantiation of the outer template compiles](http://rextester.com/QTDET12337). Moreover, [it works if you change the parameter pack to three separate template arguments](http://rextester.com/WIZ86669).

Comment: @vsoftco `ABC<int,bool,char>::DEF<4,true,'c'> foo;` works.

Comment: @Barry sorry, I misused the template, using types instead of values on the inner template. Yes, works on my side too.

Comment: The tricky part is that `DEF` actually takes a non-type template parameter pack. See the example in [temp.param]/p15.

Comment: @T.C. Is there a reason you couldn't use `value_holder::apply` in that example as a template template parameter?

Comment: The small example mentioned is from paragraph 15 (p15) of Section 14.1 (Template parameters) from the C++11 (or C++14) standard. `ABC<int,bool,char>::DEF` is essentially the same as `value_holder<int,bool,char>::apply`. I think @T.C.'s point was merely to highlight that the nested `DEF` struct template is parameterised using non-types.

Comment: @Barry My point is that `DEF`'s technically parameterized over a non-type parameter pack. And a template template argument taking a pack doesn't match a template template parameter not taking packs.

Comment: @T.C. Ah yes, I think you have it. Non-type parameters are, shall we say, more strongly typed; the same issue with type parameters will seem more obvious: `template <template <typename,typename,typename> class> struct BarT {};` cannot be instantiated with this variadic struct template: `template <typename...> struct ZodT {};` without similar errors: `BarT<ZodT> d; \\ error`

Comment: @T.C.: I have troubles understanding your point. Upon instantiation of `ABC`, `DEF` should be just a regular class template taking three non-type parameters. The fact that its parameter list is a pack expansion should not be relevant, as the template is used after that pack is expanded. Or were you just trying to figure out what might have confused the compiler? This looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @AndyProwl The (sole) parameter of `ABC<…>::DEF` is always a pack.

Comment: @Columbo: Yeah, but it is also a pack expansion, and as such it expands to a list of exactly 3 types when instantiated as in the OP's example - § 14.5.3/7.

Comment: @AndyProwl That's irrelevant. It is still a parameter pack, which is why §14.3.3/3 does not allow for a match.

Comment: @Columbo: I don't understand. Why do you assume 14.3.3/3 should be interpreted as if the pack was unexpanded? The pack expansion makes `Ts...` be a list of exactly three types, which means the nested `DEF` template has exactly 3 non-type parameters. Those are the ones that, according to 14.3.3/3, must be matched against the parameter list of `Bar`'s template template argument.

Comment: @AndyProwl No, it has one template parameter, that is a pack.

Comment: @Columbo: This does not answer my question ("Why?"). Yes it is a pack and it is also a pack expansion. What leads you to the conclusion that the pack should be treated as unexpanded when considering the rules in 14.3.3/3? (let's take it to the chat to avoid polluting this thread)

Comment: @AndyProwl I haven't responded to your question. I corrected you on the fact that there is exactly one parameter. The misunderstanding you have is that the pack expansion suddenly creates three template parameters, which is not the case. There is one parameter pack that can match three non-type template arguments of appropriate types, not more.

Comment: @Columbo: But how do you deduce that it is not the case? § 14.5.3/7 seems to imply it is: "The instantiation of a pack expansion [...] produces a list E1, E2, ..., EN. Each Ei is generated by instantiating the pattern and replacing each pack expansion parameter with its ith element. Such an element, in the context of the instantiation, is interpreted as follows: *if the pack is a template parameter pack, the element is a template parameter (14.1) of the corresponding kind (type or non-type)* designating the type or value from the template argument; [...]"

Comment: @AndyProwl Different things, but e.g. you can pass no parameters to `ABC` at all, and the instantiated template parameter list of `DEF` is still valid. This is covered by 14.5.3/7 as well, but it would not be possible if things would work as you describe, because a template without any parameters is flat out ill-formed. My answer is that the (inner) parameter pack cannot match any arguments, but is one (valid) template parameter. It can be [instantiated without arguments](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fbee6bfdf2dacad) though.

Comment: I don't know why, but aliasing helps!

template<int x, bool y, char z> using alias = ABC<int, bool, char>::DEF<x, y, z>;
Bar<alias> c;
My gcc version is 5.1

Comment: @AndyProwl What Columbo said. Call it `template<Ts... Values> struct DEF { };`; it's a pack expansion of `Ts`, but `Values` is a pack in its own right. Sure, it's a weird kind of pack compared to "normal" packs, but under the current rules it's still a pack, so the rules for packs apply. It's arguably a defect, but that's what the standard says, and what the current compilers have implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's give DEF's parameter pack a name for ease of reference:

```
template <typename ...Ts>
struct ABC {
  template <Ts ... Values>
  struct DEF {};
};
```

The key point here is that by [temp.param]/p15, `Ts... Values` is *both* a pack expansion of `Ts` and a declaration of a parameter pack `Values`.

> If a *template-parameter* is [...] a *parameter-declaration* that
>   declares a parameter pack (8.3.5), then the *template-parameter* is a
>   template parameter pack (14.5.3). A template parameter pack that is a
>   *parameter-declaration* whose type contains one or more unexpanded parameter packs is a pack expansion.

Since `DEF` takes a non-type parameter pack, it doesn't match a template template parameter that doesn't take packs ([temp.arg.template]/p3):

> A *template-argument* matches a template *template-parameter* P when
>   each of the template parameters in the
>   *template-parameter-list* of the *template-argument*’s corresponding class template or alias template A matches the corresponding template
>   parameter in the template-parameter-list of P. Two template parameters
>   match if they are of the same kind (type, non-type, template), for
>   non-type *template-parameter*s, their types are equivalent (14.5.6.1),
>   and for template *template-parameter*s, each of their corresponding
>   *template-parameter*s matches, recursively. When P’s *template-parameter-list* contains a template parameter pack (14.5.3), the template parameter pack will match zero or more template
>   parameters or template parameter packs in the
>   *template-parameter-list* of A with the same type and form as the template parameter pack in P (ignoring whether those template
>   parameters are template parameter packs).

To be sure, `Values` is rather weird for packs - for every specialization of `ABC`, `Values` must contain a fixed number of arguments - but under the current rules it's still a pack, so the rules for packs apply.

Comment: I think I understand your interpretation, but there are still unclear points to me. In particular, which "rules for packs" are you referring to? Notice, that the last part of the paragraph you quote refers to the inverse situation (i.e. when the *parameter*, rather than the argument, is a pack). The first part of the quote mentions that a template template-argument matches a template template-parameter if the corresponding template parameters match, and that these can be of three kinds: "type", "non-type", and "template". I don't see special rules for "packs", nor is "pack" a kind of parameter

Comment: @AndyProwl Right. The second half says that if there's a pack in the parameter, it can match packs and non-packs in the argument. By default, if the parameter is not a pack, then it cannot match a pack in the argument, because nothing says a (non-pack) template parameter in the parameter can match a parameter pack in the argument.

Comment: With `template<template<int...> class> struct {};`, and `Bar<ABC<int,int,int>::DEF> c;`, it compiles. But then they all have to be `int`s. So the compiler seems to make a distinction between a template argument pack, and 3 template arguments, when matching a template template argument...

Answer (score 3):

Like Barry said before about:

```
ABC<int,bool,char>::DEF<4,true,'c'> foo
```

And make a try and worked on Coliru online compiler gcc 5.1 c++14 in this site [Compiler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/):

```
#include <iostream>
 template <template <int,bool,char> class>
struct Bar {};
template <int,bool,char> struct Zod {};

Bar<Zod> a;

struct GHI {
  template <int,bool,char>
  struct JKL {};
};

Bar <GHI::JKL> b;

template <template <typename... Ts> class>
struct Base {};
template<typename... Ts>
struct Floor {};
Base<Floor> c;

template <typename... Ts>
struct ABC {
  template <Ts... val>
  struct DEF {};
};
ABC<int,bool,char>::DEF<4,true,'c'> foo;
```

I made a search and found this Template parameter list.

Pack expansion may appear in a template parameter list:

```
 template<typename... T> struct value_holder
{
    template<T... Values> // expands to a non-type template parameter 
    struct apply { };     // list, such as <int, char, int(&)[5]>
};
```

where i tested some stuff in the run code compiler at:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack
but also i found this Ellipses and Variadic Templates in visual studio 2013:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn439779.aspx